# Including header files (including themselves)

Tags: c++, class

lets say I have 3 classes. 1 base class and two derived classes. if I put these 3 in separate header files, how do I properly include them all so they all see each other? Ill post some simple sample code I found:

Polygon.h

```
// Base class


class Polygon 
{
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b;}
 };
```

triangle.h

```
class Triangle: public Polygon 
{
  public:
    int area ()
      { return width * height / 2; }
};
```

rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle: public Polygon 
{
  public:
    int area ()
      { return width * height; }
};
```

main.ccp

```
int main () 
{
  Rectangle rect;
  Triangle trgl;
  rect.set_values (4,5);
  trgl.set_values (4,5);
  cout << rect.area() << '\n';
  cout << trgl.area() << '\n';
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

I know What includes I will need I just don't know how to properly arrange them in order to make this work cleanly, thank you!

Comment: What combinations have you tried?

Comment: @TapanAnand Seems like everything, from putting everything in one global header file, to putting triangles and rectangle in polygon and including polygon in main, but no matter what i get a "includes itself error." I know theres a more efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite clearly your `Rectangle` and `Triangle` classes require `Polygon` to be defined before them, so the order should be:

```
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
```

The Last two can be in any order as they don't depend on each other.

**EDIT:**

In order to clarify why this works, when you write `#include "file.h"`, the contents of the file `file.h` are simply copied at the location of the include line. So, now to get the order right, just think what order will you keep when defining all classes in the `main.cpp` file itself and that's what the order of header files should be.

Comment: well thank you!, to be honest I was being stupid, including things everywhere, now I know thanks again

Comment: Actually yes, accepting questions is a good practice around here. You do it by clicking the ticket at the left of the answer.